# Are PTHREAD_MUTEX_* and PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK mutually exclusive?

Tags: pthreads, mutex

The Open Group has a specification for `pthread_mutex_lock`, `pthread_mutex_trylock`, `pthread_mutex_unlock` and friends located [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html).

The page lists four mutex attribute values: `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL`, `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK`, `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`, and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT`.

Are all the values mutually exclusive? In a Debug configuration, are we allowed to `OR` those values together? For example, I'd like full error checking in Debug, so is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK | PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` a valid configuration?

The reason I ask is I'm catching an error `pthread_mutexattr_settype`.  I'm not sure if its a valid configuration and an OS X implementation bug; or if its an invalid configuration and expected standard behavior. If its an OS X bug, I can still enjoy the enhanced error checking in debug configurations on other platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mutex can be of only one "type".  You cannot combine them.

It doesn't really make sense to do so, anyway - `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` mutexes always return an error if you try to relock a mutex already locked by the same thread, whereas `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` mutexes always succeed in that case.  In the other error-checking cases (unlocking a mutex which another thread has locked, and unlocking an unlocked mutex) both `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` have the same behaviour (always returning an error).

This means that your `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` mutexes should remain the same type in "debug" builds, but it might make sense to substitute `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` for `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` mutexes.

Comment: Thanks Caf. "In the other error-checking cases..." - that's the problem (for me). I don't know how much additional checking occurs when "Error Checking" is in effect. If pthreads skips some checks in the name of efficiency, then I want those checks performed. I've never understood the "let's do the wrong thing quickly" mindset. If its broken, then it does not matter how fast you do it.

Comment: @noloader: The POSIX doesn't allow the error checks to be omitted in the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` case - the only difference between `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` is what happens in the relock-a-mutex-already-held case.  It's only `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` that have the undefined-behaviour cases.  The philosophy behind the undefined behaviour cases is that a correct application should not have to pay the overhead costs of checking for errors in incorrect applications.